# Nginx is not accepting range of bytes

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, video-streaming, html5-video

I am using nginx to serve videos from the file system. I would like to enable range request.

Currently this is the result returned for my file

```
curl -I fileurl
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 29 Mar 2014 06:41:41 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 15603963
Last-Modified: Sat, 04 Jan 2014 15:02:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=300
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

But if I send 
    curl --header "Range: bytes=0-50" fileurl

the whole file is downloaded.

This is the server in nginx config:

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name myserver;
            error_log logs/myserver.error.log;
            access_log logs/myserver.access.log;

            root /srv/myserver;

            #add_header Accept-Ranges;
            add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;
    }
```

Do I have to enable anything else? How could I allow range requests for the files?

Comment: Boring Video I expected a cinema blockbuster under that url :-)

Comment: I "expected" assistance in the comments :)

(Judging could sometimes be boring. Actual competitions are not ;) ).

Comment: I have no experience with nginx I was just interested. In general you should not post real urls, so I cannot rate the video and you have less traffic for the question it's not relevant.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind. For the current case I hope that with a real url someone could more easily test the server.

Comment: The testing would be only easier if you would allow also modifying the config files, but that is of cause bloody dangerous.

Comment: You might be right. I have removed the real urls.

Comment: @thebravoman What is actually serving the file? Is it nginx or is it being passed to a backend?

Comment: @Danack - it is nginx

Comment: This issue is crucial for auto-playback of (muted) html5-videos on iOS-devices.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to get range requests working after adding the following line to my nginx site config

```
    proxy_force_ranges on;
```

You can read more about it [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_force_ranges)

Comment: Man I love you, I've been struggling to get range requests working on my nginx for hours, tried everything, only your hint worked.. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 4):

I have found it - its the option

```
max_ranges
```

It was max_ranges 0 at the bottom of the configuration.

Comment: Only by default `max_ranges` is not supposed to be zero and you did not show that line in your question! In my case, I have `max_ranges 100;` and it still isn't doing it right.

Answer (score -3):

The content type for .m4v files is `video/x-m4v`, I don't think `video/mp4` will work for those.